# bash script - output in color using printf

Tags: bash

hi guys I'm working on a project but i wanted to display the output text in color.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s" "this is in red";
printf "%s" "this is in default color";
exit 0
```

this is the example and how would I display "this is in red" in red and leave the rest of the output text on default color?

i looked at some examples but they were all for echo and it did not really worked for printf or do i really have to use echo to make it work?

any help will be great. thanks

Comment: Read the [Bash How To](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) which contains details about coloring

Comment: its using echo will it work for printf @martialdidit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below example

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "\x1b[31m\"this is in red\"\x1b[0m\n";
printf "this is in default color\n";
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Color is achieved by sending ANSI escape sequences to the terminal that instruct the terminal to display the following text in a different color. `printf` makes it easy to generate the necessary character sequences, because it interprets (among other things) `\e` to be an ASCII escape character.

Specifically, you tell the terminal to start displaying red characters by print the sequence `\e[31m` (that's 5 characters: ASCII 27 (escape), `[`, `3`, `1`, and `m`). To tell the terminal to use the default color (whatever that is for the terminal), output `\e[0m`. Putting it together:

```
printf '\e[31m%s\e[0m' "this is in red"
printf "%s" "this is in default color"
```

Comment: thanks! definitely helped me to understand the concept :)